# How can I dispose an object

Tags: c#, .net, data-structures, linked-list, idisposable

I am trying to delete a Node from a linked list. Below is the code I have tried.

```
public class Node : IDisposable
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public Node Next { get; set; }

    public Node(int value)
    {
        this.Value = value;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            Next.Dispose();
        }
    }
}

public class LinkedList
{
    Node head;
    public void CreateList()
    {
        Node node1 = new Node(1);
        Node node2 = new Node(2);
        Node node3 = new Node(3);

        head = node1;
        node1.Next = node2;
        node2.Next = node3;
    }

    public void DeleteLastItem()
    {
            Node prevNode = head;
            Node nextNode = head;

            while (nextNode.Next != null)
            {
                prevNode = nextNode;
                nextNode = nextNode.Next;
            }
            prevNode.Next = null;
            nextNode.Dispose();
    }
}
```

I wanted to dispose the `nextNode` (which is nothing but the last node. And it will not be part of the Linked List).

When I try above code, I am getting below exception:

> Unhandled Exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

How can I proceed here ? How can I dispose a `Node` object?

Comment: What makes you think a `Node` needs to be disposed of? Also, why are you writing your own linked list instead of using [the built-in one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he2s3bh7.aspx)?

Comment: @Jon Could be for learning purposes.

Comment: I know GC will dispose the node automatically. Also, LinkedList class is present .NET. I am doing this just for my interest to know the internal things.

Comment: the IDisposable interface / pattern is meant to be used when a manged type uses native resources that need to be released.

Comment: @Bunyip No, the GC will *not* dispose of the node automatically.  The entire `IDisposable` patter exists to allow for the disposal of resources that the GC is unable to properly clean up.  If you have no such unmanaged resources then there is no reason to implement `IDisposable`.

Comment: See this article, I think it will clear you some concepts: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15360/Implementing-IDisposable-and-the-Dispose-Pattern-P

Comment: The point is not that the GC is unable to free those resources, usually you call Dispose in your finalizer (destructor), so the resources will be released eventually, the point of the IDisposable interface is that you have the choice *when* you want to release those resources

Comment: @Bunyip: The important thing to note here is that **these nodes do not need disposing**. If there were unmanaged resources in play then we could start talking about disposing, but as it stands you are running around in circles for no reason.

Comment: @RobertJ. Not true.  You cannot rely on a finalizer to be run; it's merely a safety net.

Comment: @Jon : This is the first time I tried Dispose(). Yes...it is a great learning for me today. I shall use these best practices.

Comment: @Servy I didnt mean to imply that you can rely on finalizers. On a sidenode: What good is a safety net that you cant rely on? ;)

Comment: @RobertJ.: Then a safety net is not such a good analogy. More like the tires around a race track that minimises the damage when you forget to turn...

Comment: @Guffa: I dont think so, a good analogy would be placing tires at *some* places, and concrete walls on some others, so you'll never be sure, but enough of that ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `Dispose(bool)` method, you can only dispose the next node if there is one. Check for a null reference before you attempt that:

```
protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing) {
  if (disposing) {
    if (Next != null) {
      Next.Dispose();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I guess you should simply check if Next is not null before calling Dispose on it.

When the Dispose method is called on any node, you manually call the next one so one you will reach the last one, the Next property will be null therefore you get this exception.

Considering the code you gave, I don't see why you would need your node to be disposable. It is only necessary if you use non managed resources which is not the case in the code you gave (but maybe you simplified it for the question).

Answer (score 1):

In your Dispose logic, check for NULL:

```
public class Node : IDisposable
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public Node Next { get; set; }

    public Node(int value)
    {
        this.Value = value;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            if (Next != null) // <-- new code here
            {
                Next.Dispose();
            }                 
        }
    }
}
```